# Replace add to cart button for unlogged users in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I don't want to show product add to cart button for unlogged users. I am using the code bellow changing add to cart button:

```
// Replace add to cart button with link for users who aren't logged in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    // Logged in users see add to cart button
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) return;

    $button_text = __( "Sign up for pricing", "woocommerce" );
    $button = '<div><a class="button" href="https://example.com/link">' . $button_text . '</a></div>';

    return $button;
}
```

It works on all pages except on single  product pages. The product page continues to show the default add to cart button. What am I missing?

Comment: Just made a more convenient update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Added button link on single products to My account login URL

The following will do it all you want in a better way (replacing your code):

```
// Replacing the button add to cart by a link to the product page in Shop and archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    // Only for unlogged user
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){
        $button_text = __( "Sign up for pricing", "woocommerce" );
        // $button_link = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ); // Login Url
        $button_link = $product->get_permalink(); // Single product Url
        $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    }

    return $button;
}

// Replacing the single product button add to cart by a custom button
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'disabled_single_add_to_cart_button', 1 );
function disabled_single_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;

    // Only for unlogged user
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){

        // For variable product types (keeping attribute select fields)
        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'custom_product_button', 20 );
        }
        // For all other product types
        else {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_product_button', 30 );
        }
    }
}

// The custom replacement button function inked to loggin page
function custom_product_button(){
    $login_url = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );
    echo '<a class="button" href="'.$login_url.'">' . __( "Sign up for pricing", "woocommerce" ) . '</a>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

> To make a disabled button on single product page use instead:
>
> ```
> // The custom replacement button function with a disabled button
> function custom_product_button(){
>     echo '<a class="button disabled">' . __( "Sign up for pricing", "woocommerce" ) . '</a>';
> }
> ```

---

To Hide prices on shop and archive pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'remove_woocommerce_loop_price', 2 );
function remove_woocommerce_loop_price() {
    // Only for unlogged user
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
}
```

To remove product price from single product pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_woocommerce_single_price', 2 );
function remove_woocommerce_single_price() {
    // Only for unlogged user
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
}


// Hide variations price for variable products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'hide_variations_price_html', 10, 3) ;
function hide_variations_price_html( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    // Only for unlogged user
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        $data['price_html'] = ' ';

    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for the code! Works great on product details page, but the "products" page still shows the add to cart button for non logged in users