# Replace "Add to cart" for guests with "Log in or Register to buy" Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to replace "Add to cart button" for GUESTS with "Log in or Register to buy" button with link to register/login page.

This [Replace add to cart button for unlogged users in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63094657/11987538) (part 1) answer code is something very similar to what I need.

I replaced

```php
// $button_link = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ); // Login Url
```

With

```
// $button_link = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'mans-konts' ) ); // Login Url
```

But:

- It's not working for me, maybe I'am editing wrong fields (edited only login url)? Which fields should be edited?
- I need it to work only for certain category not all shop, is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace add to cart button for unlogged users in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63094526/replace-add-to-cart-button-for-unlogged-users-in-woocommerce)

Comment: _"It's not working for me, maybe I'am editing wrong fields?"_. How is someone supposed to be able to answer that if you don't mention which fields you've modified?

Comment: Sorry, edited post.

Comment: **1)** This line `// $button_link = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'mans-konts' ) );` is in comment, by the `//` in front. It means that you either choose the first line of code, or the 2nd. By putting 1 of the 2 in comment tags, and the other not. Too bad you indicate that something doesn't work while it works. **2)** _"I need it to work only for certain category"_. Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. Please edit your question to show [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code, first method removes the add to cart button from product loops, second method adds a new add to cart button

```
function remove_loop_button(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','replace_add_to_cart');
function replace_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;
    $link = $product->get_permalink();

    echo do_shortcode('<a  href="'.$link.'" class="button add_to_cart_button">'.$product->add_to_cart_text().'</a>');
}
```

Comment: Not working, and how I understand it is not for certain category? It's very important for me that button is replaces only for certain category.